# Two levels of options in add to cart form

Tags: commerce

I am working with a project of sofas. Clients can choose the size and the fabric. In each fabric there are several colours.
What I need is that the client chooses the fabric and then the form shows the colors of the selected fabric so the cliente can choose too.
Is that posible?

Answer (score 0):

This is not how Drupal Commerce normally works w/ attributes - you typically define all of the possible variants as SKUs, associate them all together on the Add to Cart form, and show a form with both attribute select lists shown at once. You can alter that form to your heart's content, though, hiding one select list until another is adjusted - but note that Drupal Commerce also doesn't support an attribute not having a selection out of the box. This is a technical limitation of how the form is designed to work, but there is an open issue in the queue trying to support that.

Comment: That is the point where I am. I discover the way of creating taxonomy vocabularies, one per fabric. Then the color of each fabric as taxonomy term. The problem now is how to do that client only can select one color of one target. Maybe some ajax solution? Any idea?

Comment: The perfect solution should be to create only one vocaulary. The parent terms will be the fabrics and each fabric would have the color as children but all the terms, parents and children are at the same level in add to cart form. Is there a way to organize them with jquery? I can't find the way because there is no class in attrs that tells me which ones are parents and which one are children. Any help would be great.